# get serviceInstanceName and serviceKeyName for cloud foundry user provider serves by using cloudFoundryOperations

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-java-client

im trying to get the Credentials of UPS in cloud foundry:
using:

```
Mono<ServiceKey> serviceKey = (Mono<ServiceKey>) cloudFoundryOperations
    .services()
    .getServiceKey(
        GetServiceKeyRequest.builder()
            .serviceKeyName("digital_cassandra")
            .serviceInstanceName("2a5aa377-e992-4f88-9f85-d9cec5c3bea9")
            .build())
    .subscribe();

serviceKey.map(serviceKey1 -> {
    System.out.println(serviceKey1.getCredentials().toString());
    return serviceKey1.getCredentials().get(0);
});
```

but nothing printed.
how to fet the serviceKeyName and serviceInstanceName by cloudFoundryOperations?
i need to print all the serviceKeyName  and serviceInstanceName in my space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .serviceInstanceName("2a5aa377-e992-4f88-9f85-d9cec5c3bea9")

It should be the actual name, not the guid. Like "my-key" or whatever you called your key.

> but nothing printed. how to fet the serviceKeyName and serviceInstanceName by cloudFoundryOperations?

If you just want to print to the console, try something like this:

```
        cloudFoundryOperations
            .services()
            .getServiceKey(GetServiceKeyRequest.builder()
                    .serviceInstanceName("reservation-db")
                    .serviceKeyName("cf-mysql")
                    .build())
            .doOnNext(key -> {
                System.out.println("Key:");
                System.out.println("  " + key.getName() + " (" + key.getId() + ")");
                key.getCredentials().forEach((k, v) -> {
                    System.out.println("    " + k + " => " + v);
                });
            })
            .block();
```

The GetServiceKeyRequest determines which service key is looked up. The `doOnNext` call allows you to inspect but not consume the key, which works fine to print it out. Then the example calls `.block()` to wait for the results, which is fine cause this is just an example. You wouldn't want to do that in your actual code though. You'd probably want one of the `subscribe()` variants (you could swap `subscribe()` for `doOnNext()` too, just depends on what you're code is doing).

> i need to print all the serviceKeyName and serviceInstanceName in my space.

To get all the keys for all the service instances:

```
       cloudFoundryOperations
           .services()
           .listInstances()
           .doOnNext(si -> {
               System.out.println("  " + si.getName() + "  (" + si.getId() + ")");
           })
           .flatMap((ServiceInstanceSummary si) -> {
                return ops
                      .services()
                      .listServiceKeys(ListServiceKeysRequest.builder()
                              .serviceInstanceName(si.getName())
                              .build())
                      .doOnNext(key -> {
                            System.out.println("Key:");
                            System.out.println("  " + key.getName() + " (" + key.getId() + ")");
                            key.getCredentials().forEach((k, v) -> {
                                System.out.println("    " + k + " => " + v);
                            });
                      });
           })
           .blockLast();
```

This one is enumerating all the service instances, printing the name/id, then using `flatMap` to go out and get the service keys for each service instance. It then merges them all into one `Flux<ServiceKey>`. The `doOnNext()` is just for printing. You don't necessarily have to do that. You could consume the result in a number of ways, like collect it into a list or subscribe to it, this just works nicely for an example. Use what works best for your code.